# How to use a bash file to execute a loadScript in geth console on private blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

I'm trying to use a bash file to execute a loasdScript file in geth console on a private blockchain.
How can I do this?

I have tried:

```
\\Bash file

$ geth --exec 'loadScript("/path/to/file/filename.js")' attach ipc:/path/to/ipc
```

But it doesn't worked.

Also tried:

```
\\Bash file

geth --preload "/my/scripts/folder/utils.js,/my/scripts/folder/contracts.js" console
```

But, not worked also.

Hope someone could help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: I can't leave this as a comment, but can you please provide more information why the scripts failed to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution from the problem through this:

```
 ./geth --jspath "path/to/file.js" --exec "eth.namereg(loadScript('file.js'))"" attach ipc:folder/geth.ipc
```

Hope could be usefull for someone.